# How to setup deployment to the remote SSH server using pipelines

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, laravel-envoy

I'm creating pipeline which will responsible to run deployment script on my remote server when I commit changes to develop branch. I am using laravel envoyer. what I need is just to run `envoy run deploy` on my remote server after commit.

I was using steps described [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html)

Here is bitbucket-pipelines.yml config

```
pipelines:
 branches:
  develop:
   - step:
    script:
     - ssh -t user@example.com
     - cd /var/www/project_folder/html
     - envoy run deploy
```

Infinite execution happening and I get following message

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.236.241.243' to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-138-generic x86_64)
 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud
156 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
*** System restart required ***
mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shows what is wrong, your server needs a restart, also the next two commands will not be executed on the remote server, change the ssh command to include the commands to execute on the remote server:

```
ssh -t user@example.com "cd /var/www/project_folder/html && envoy run deploy"
```